# Problema para con la documentación e instalación waipy

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola estoy tratando de trabajar con la librería PyWavelets, por que necesito usar la transformada de wavelet (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformada_ond%C3%ADcula) (https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

El código de instalación de PyWavelets es el siguiente:

```
pip install waipy
```

El problema es que estoy tratando de usar los ejemplos de la siguiente página: file:///C:/Users/Hola/Desktop/Wavelet%20analysis%20in%20Python%20_%20cracking%20the%20climate%20code.html

Pero cuando escribo el siguiente código:

```
import waipy
```

en mi terminal me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
  File "prueba_waipy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import waipy 
  File "C:\Users\Hola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\waipy\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from .cwt.lib_wavelet import nextpow2
  File "C:\Users\Hola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\waipy\cwt\lib_wavelet.py", line 48
"""CAUTION : default values"""
                              ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

PS C:\Users\Hola\Documents\programas_tesis\Pywavelets>

¿Que podría ser?, ¿Las librerías de los ejemplos de la pagina están desactualizadas?, Instale la libreria que se necesita, pero con solo import waipy no corre.

Comment: Te estas confundiendo de modulos. El ejemplo que mostraste no se parece al de la documentación de [PyWavelets](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), es de [waipy](https://github.com/mabelcalim/waipy). Se habran olvidado de actualizar [el paquete en PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/waipy/#history). Prueba instalandolo directamente desde github con `pip install -U git+https://github.com/mabelcalim/waipy.git`.

Comment: @braver me sale el siguiente mensaje: Collecting git+https://github.com/mabelcalim/waipy.git
  Cloning https://github.com/mabelcalim/waipy.git to c:\users\hola\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-kg6fk4ju
  ERROR: Error [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/mabelcalim/waipy.git 'C:\Users\Hola\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kg6fk4ju'
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

Comment: Tienes dos opciones: 1) instalar git y volver a intentar o 2) bajar [el zip del repositorio](https://github.com/mabelcalim/waipy/archive/master.zip), descomprimirlo y desde dentro de la carpeta donde esta el setup.py hacer `pip install .` (nota el punto al final que hace que instale desde el mismo directorio).

Comment: @braver ya tengo instalado waipy y cuando corro solamente: "import waipy" me da el mensaje: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @braver he instalado pip install . y tengo el mismo problema

Comment: que raro, lo probe con una instalacion limpia y parecia funcionar, asi que no se que pueda estar pasando. Tambien podrias intentar instalarlo en un [entorno virtual](https://www.programaenpython.com/miscelanea/crear-entornos-virtuales-en-python/) para que no entre en conflicto con otros paquetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PyWavelets` es una cosa, y otra `waipy`. El módulo que te falla es este último.

Mirando en el repositorio, https://github.com/mabelcalim/waipy, se ve que el fichero que falla fue cambiado en el [commit 1d5a523](https://github.com/mabelcalim/waipy/commit/1d5a523129774485a39b352db2a5c3b01d45fabb#diff-c4766a69fa861018c53bc05f8c55082c) para adaptarlo al **estilo PEP8**. A partir de este *commit*, ninguno de los cambios se han *consolidado* para subirlos a PyPi, por lo que la instalación con `pip install waipy` instala un módulo antiguo (waipy-0.0.9.0) sin ninguna de las últimas correcciones.

Para evitar problemas, hay que desinstalar `waipy` antes de hacer nada:

```
pip uninstall waipy
```

A continuación, hay que seguir las [instrucciones de instalación](https://github.com/mabelcalim/waipy/blob/master/README.md#installation), descargando el repostorio, instalándolo con `setup.py` e instalando todas las dependencias a mano, tal como se indica.

Comment: Y cuál es la diferencia de los dos?

Comment: Una es la versión estable, pero no usable con las últimas versiones de python, y la otra es la versión de desarrollo, pero que podría tener funcionamiento distinto del documentado (vamos, que es probable que tengas que leer el código para saber cómo funciona).